# i am making text changes on my page show in preview not on live site, why?

Tags: publish, wp-editor

I go into the admin back room on my site make text changes and hit preview changes and they show up, but when i go to the live site, they don't show at all.  What am i missing, what should i be doing?

Comment: do you have any caching plugins installed?

Comment: Are you "Publishing"? Or just pressing the "Preview" button?

Answer (score 1):

Changes made to pages and posts are not saved when you *Preview*, they are only applied and made public when you *Publish* or *Update*.

As mentioned above, caching plugins may prevent the changes from being displayed immediately even if you're saved your edits.